# facing problem while adding to a linked list, two seemingly identical codes are giving very different results

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

i am here trying to add a node to a singlylinkedlist

```
SinglyLinkedListNode s = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
  if(head == null){SinglyLinkedList a = new SinglyLinkedList();
  a.head = s;
  return a.head;}
  else{
      SinglyLinkedListNode a = head;
      while(head.next != null){
          head = head.next;}
        head.next = s;
        return a;
  }
```

this one works but if i do this -

```
 SinglyLinkedListNode s = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
  if(head == null){SinglyLinkedList a = new SinglyLinkedList();
  a.head = s;
  return a.head;}
  else{
      SinglyLinkedListNode a = head;
      while(head != null){
          head = head.next;}
        head = s;
        return a;
  }
```

some how the list now contains only one node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code while loop terminates when `head.next != null`, after termination head will point to last node in the linked list and when you do `head.next = s` it will append new node to you existing list.

In your second code while loop terminates when `head == null`, after termination head will point to `null`. so now you are assigning `head = s` so head will point to newly created node and it is not appended to your original list.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple to find out with debugging step by step, and I guess that is way to learn it... try out putting break point at while loop and next line (assigning value directly to `head`), and check values of variables (mostly F8 key for debugging)...

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: @shivam - did it help?

Comment: someone answered the question below , so i did not have to